# How can I hold down in Minecraft whilst tabbed out?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any way I could hold down the mouse button **whilst being tabbed out**?
My goal is to be able to have **multiple windows** running at the same time on 1 PC, all of them holding down **W** and **LMB**.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Minecraft doesn't pause when losing focus. You can do this by hitting F3+P.

Once you did that, you can do the input you want to persist and hit F3+T. This will reload your resources. While you see the loading screen release your input. After Minecraft is done reloading, your input should remain active without pressing anything.

> This is pretty useful for AFK Fishing in 1.15 and below as you don't need any macros with this trick.